# Adapters with Entity framework (C#)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, adapter

I'm trying to use entity framework with an adapter structure, my goal will be to have a single .edmx structure able to manage several connections.

I need to have those adapters:

- file based database (SqlServerCE 3.5)
- MySql (with its custom provider from Oracle)
- Oracle (as MySql)
- SqlServer

I have a DAO class that receives a bean (dependency injection object) with data connection from a winform, than due to a specific info in that bean, the DAO will load the correct adapter, through a Database factory class.

My Database factory will load a real adaptor class (e.g. for mysql A_Mysql.cs that implement my abstract adapter class).

In particular, I would like to understand hop I can modify in the adaptor the connection method:

```
public override Entities createConnection(DbConnection dbBean)
    {
        string conn =
          @"metadata=res://*/Toolkit.Database.External.ADO.ADODatabase.csdl" +
          @"|res://*/Toolkit.Database.External.ADO.ADODatabase.ssdl" +
          @"|res://*/Toolkit.Database.External.ADO.ADODatabase.msl;" +
          @"provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;" +
          "provider connection string=\"Persist Security Info=True;server=" + dbBean.Server + ";" +
          "Port=" + dbBean.Port + ";" +
          "User Id=" + dbBean.Username + ";"+
          "Password=" + dbBean.Password + ";" +
          "database=" + dbBean.Schema + "\"";

        Entities entities = new Entities(conn);

        return entities;
    }
```

to use the same .edmx, in my DAO…

I was pretty sure that this was the right way, unfortunately this system is always returning me errors from SqlCE (I have generated the first .emdx from SqlServerCE, but it does not contain any informations about that database and my App.config file has NOT stored database informations)…

Can you help me? Please write me back for further information, if needed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your data access layer will need to be abstracted at the entity provider level, not the database connection level. You're basically talking about using the repository pattern. You will need to have a separate context for each provider you plan to support, because that's ultimately what's responsible for translating your Linq queries into the correct SQL syntax for a specific database platform. Each context should implement the same interface (which is your repository interface). In your code, you do everything against that interface, not the actual context types. Then use a Dependency Injection framework (such as Ninject) to manage instantiating the correct context implementation for the database provider you're using.

Comment: Can you help me? I still have some difficulties: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903988/modify-ssdl-runtime-for-ado-net-and-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because EDMX itself contains information about database provider. Also whole database description stored in EDMX targets single database provider. There is even difference between SQL Server 2005 and 2008. You need at least separate SSDL part for every database you want to support.

Comment: Can you help me? I still have some difficulties: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903988/modify-ssdl-runtime-for-ado-net-and-entity-framework)